# I just started learning python and I am struggling with trying to save high scores and displaying the high score once the game is done

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have made a simple archery game and i am trying to create a scoreboard and display the high score at the end of the game but i am having trouble due to being new to python coding.  Can anyone help? thanks in advance!

```
import turtle
import random
import time
scrin = turtle.Screen()
scrin.bgcolor("red")
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.pensize(4)
t.speed(5)
r = 180  # biggest circle
y = -r                  
for i in ["white", "grey", "blue", "red", "yellow"]:
t.penup()    
t.goto(0, y)
t.pendown
t.color(i)          
t.fillcolor(i)      
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(r)
t.end_fill()        
r -= 50       # circle reduced by 50
y = -r        # circle starting position (0, -r)
t.hideturtle()
scrin.exitonclick()

import turtle
from random import randint

t1 = turtle.Turtle()

t1.shape('arrow')
t1.penup()
t1.goto(randint(-100,0),randint(0,100))

turtle.done()
import turtle
from random import randint

t1 = turtle.Turtle()


t1.shape('arrow')
t1.penup()
t1.goto(randint(-100,0),randint(0,100))

turtle.done()

import turtle
from random import randint

t1 = turtle.Turtle()

t1.shape('arrow')
t1.penup()
t1.goto(randint(-100,0),randint(0,100))

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please ask a specific technical question about your attempt at implementing a feature rather than drop a broad feature request with no attempt. Thanks.

Comment: _but i am having trouble_ Trouble with what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could save your high score in a scores.txt file. Here is a code snippet that could be used to create and write your high score to the file:

```
#Clear the file
with open('scores.txt', 'r+') as f:
   f.truncate(0)
#Write new high score
with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write(--SCORE HERE--)
```

And another code snippet thats used to read the high score:

```
with open('scores.txt', 'r') as f:
   high_score = int(f.read())
```

Comment: It is marking "bad input" on "f.write(--SCORE HERE--) i tried changing the spacing but so far it is still giving me the error.

Comment: Replace --SCORE HERE-- with your high score, formatted as a string.